# How to scroll current line to the center of screen in PyCharm 1.5.4 with emacs keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I try to figure out how to center the current line in the center through PyCharm.
The default key binding of emacs is C-u C-l but it doesn't work in PyCharm.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such action in PyCharm, feel free to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Does PyCharm provide a keymap indicating which key binding of emacs is support?

Comment: The "create issue" feature on that website appears to be broken :P

Comment: While this answer possibly was correct in 2011, at least pycharm 2018.1 does have this feature.

Answer (score 6):

The default key binding for this is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.

Go to *File* -> *Settings*, then *Keymap*, then *Editor Actions* -> *Scroll to Center*. There you find the feature, and you can remap it to any other binding.

This is an Intellij-Idea IDE feature and not limited to the PyCharm editor.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to: Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Virtual Space -> Show virtual space at file bottom

   Tick it.
   [image]
2. Add a Keyboard Shortcut for Scroll line to middle. Ctrl+l
   [image]